# Change DisplayName and ID of objects of an S3 bucket by AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli, bucket

I have a bucket that has objects with two possible owners (kafka and dataware).
When I run a get-object-acl of some object, it comes like this.

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "dataware",
        "ID": "123456abc"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "dataware",
                "ID": "123456abc",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible, through AWS CLI, to manually change the display name to kafka and its ID (or the opposite)? Something like this?

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "kafka",
        "ID": "987654aaa"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "kafka",
                "ID": "987654aaa",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `aws s3api put-object-acl` to change the owner of an existing object. Also consider S3 feature "Object ownership" - causes the bucket to disable ACL's which basically means the bucket owner owns all newly created files regardless of who created them. (And be very careful when editing ACLs :)

Comment: I ran the CLI command with put-object-acl:
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket bucketdatabases --acl bucket-owner-full-control \ --access-control-policy DisplayName=kafka,ID=987654aaa \ --key database/tablename/yearmonthday=20210810/file.avro
but receiving this error: Unknown options: \, \